# Justifying steps in Riesz Representation theorem (local compact hausdorff space case)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, geometry, riesz-representation-theorem

I am reading the proof of  Riesz Representation theorem(1.5.14) on [Leon Simon's book:Geometric Measure Theory](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Elms/ntu-gmt-text.pdf)

And I got stuck at the following higlighted part. I completely understand the note he made befor the highlight part but I just cant reach his conclusion using that note.
For your information: $$L(g)=\int_{X} g\cdot\nu d\mu$$ is proved .And $f \in C_c(X,[0,\infty))$, $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is helpful, but I noticed looking at the textbook that the condition he gives is $f\in K_+$, not $f\in C_c(X,\mathbb R^n)$,

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, i know, and that is also the reason that I dont know the way to apply the fact he is going to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to find $g \in C_c(X, \mathbb{R}^n)$ with $|g| \leq f$ and $|L(g)|$ arbitrarily close to $\int_X f |v| \, d \mu$.
Let us therefore look at $g_k = f\hat{g}_k$, since then we have $|g_k| \leq f$ from $|\hat{g}_k| \leq 1$.
Next, by the triangle inequality we have

$\displaystyle \Bigg||L(g_k)| - \int_X f|v| \, d\mu \Bigg| \leq \Bigg|L(g_k) - \int_X f|v| \, d\mu \Bigg| \leq \int_X \big| g_k \cdot v -  f|v| \big| \, d\mu$.

Now, using the trick that $|v| = \hat{v} \cdot v$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get

$\displaystyle \int_X \big| g_k \cdot v -  f|v| \big| \, d\mu = \int_X f|(\hat{g}_k - \hat{v}) \cdot v| \, d\mu \leq \int_X f|v||\hat{g}_k - \hat{v}| \, d\mu$.

Finally, it is mentioned earlier in your source that $v$ is a bounded function.
The same is true of $f$ (being a continuous function of compact support).
It therefore follows that $f|v|$ is bounded, and so by Hölder's inequality we get

$\displaystyle \int_X f|v||\hat{g}_k - \hat{v}| \, d\mu \leq \big|\big| f|v| \big|\big|_\infty \int_X |\hat{g}_k - \hat{v}| \, d\mu$

where the right hand side can be made arbitrarily small.
We have thus shown what we wanted to show.

Comment: I believe the last line you mean $f|v|$ bound so inequality follows instead of Hölder. But thanks, you provide a good answer to my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah I guess Hölder is a bit overkill. Anyway, glad my answer was of help.